# Writing multiple partition specs to Apache Iceberg table

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-iceberg

I would like to write an Iceberg table with a different partition spec than the default table settings so that when I run data compaction the data would be compacted according to the default spec (as possible with the `write-format` config)

For example:

```scala
df.writeStream
  .format("iceberg")
  .outputMode("append")
  .options(Map("path" ->tableIdentifier,
                  "checkpointLocation" -> checkpointLocation,
                  "fanout-enabled" -> "true",
                   "spec-id" ->"3"))
```

Theoretically, it should be fine as Iceberg knows how to handle multiple partitions specs as mentioned here [Partition Evolution](https://iceberg.apache.org/#evolution/#partition-evolution).
Practically, I haven't found a way to do it.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs [Streaming writes](https://iceberg.apache.org/#spark-structured-streaming/#streaming-writes), I think you can't specify partitions while writing stream. Maybe you can try adding the new partition field before writing, using [ALTER TABLE SQL extensions](https://iceberg.apache.org/#spark-ddl/#alter-table-sql-extensions) available for Spark 3.x:

```sql
ALTER TABLE tmp.db.sample ADD PARTITION FIELD years(date)
```

For [batch writes](https://iceberg.apache.org/#spark-writes/#writing-with-dataframes), partition expressions are now supported in `partitionBy` using Spark 3 new `DataFrameWriterV2` API:

```scala
data.writeTo("tmp.db.table")
    .tableProperty("write.format.default", "orc")
    .partitionBy($"level", days($"ts"))
    .createOrReplace()
```